# Synchronisation: Client, Server Chat

Tags: multithreading, client, chat, synchronization

I am writing a Client, Server-based chat. The Server is the central component and handles all the incoming messages and outgoing messages. The clients are that chat users. They see the chat in a frame and can also write chat messages. These messages are sent over to the server. The server in turn updates all clients.

My problem is synchronisation of the clients. Since the server is multi-threaded, both messages can be received from clients and updates (in form of messages) have to be sent out aswell. Since each client is getting updated in in its own thread, there is no guarantee that all clients will receive the same messages. We have a snychronisation problem.

How do I solve it?

I have messed with timestamps and a buffer. But this is not a good solution again because there is no guarantee that after assigning a timestamp the message will be put into the buffer immediately afterwards.

I shall add that I do not know the clients. That is, I only have one open connection in each thread on the server. I do not have an array of clients or something like that to keep track of all the clients.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you implement a queue for each client proxy (that's the object that manages the communication with each client). 
Each iteration of your server object's (on its own thread) work:
1. It reads messages from the queues of all client proxies first
2. Decides if it needs to send out any messages based on its internal logic and incoming messages
3. Prepares and puts any outgoing messages to the queues of all its client proxies.

The client proxy thread work schedule is this:
1. Read from the communication.
2. Write to the queue from client proxy to server (if received any messages).
3. Read from the queue from server to client proxy.
4. Write to communication channel to client (if needed).

You may have to have a mutex on each queue.
Hope that helps